# Notepad++ Remove zeroes after decimal place and two digits

Tags: regex, notepad++

I'm trying to use Notepad++ find and replace feature.

I would like to remove all zeroes after a decimal place and two digits.

So:

- `1234.5600` would become `1234.56`
- `2.3000` would become `2.30`

Thanks for your time

Comment: Is `123.456700` required to become `123.45` or `123.4567`?

Comment: @Toto I had a CSV which had prices listed, but had 4 digits after the decimal place, the last two were zeroes. This was messing up a program I was using to import the data, so I just needed to remove the trailing zeroes. (So all of the prices were **.**00, the two zeroes at the end needed to be removed)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use regex in notepad++ `Replace` dialog box

1. Open Replace
2. Check that `Regular Expression` is selected.
3. In `Find what`, put `(\d+\.\d{2})\d*`
4. In `Replace with`, put `\1`
5. Replace All